# Rccp.h not found in Renjin when compiling package

Tags: r, rcpp, renjin

I want to compile the `units` package in Renjin, which currently does not work in the online repository, see http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/units/0.6-3/build/5

- I created a `pom.xml` for the current release of udunits, see https://github.com/nuest/renjin-docker/blob/master/geospatial-packages/units/pom.xml
- I built a Dockerfile for compiling packages and having the required compilers, see https://github.com/nuest/renjin-docker/blob/master/0.9.2726/Dockerfile.builder
- Within a container created from an image built from that Dockerfile, I can run `library('org.renjin.cran:Rcpp')` in an R session, but when I run `mvn clean install` on `units` I get the following error:

```
[...]

Downloaded: https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/aether/aether-impl/1.13.1/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar (128 KB at 7.4 KB/sec)
EXECUTING: -print-file-name=plugin
EXECUTING: -shared -xc++ -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/plugin/include -fPIC -fno-rtti -O2 plugin.c -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc -o /packages/units/units/target/bridge.so
configure: units: 0.6-4
Warning: unsupported configuration variable CFLAGS
Warning: unsupported configuration variable CPPFLAGS
Warning: unsupported configuration variable LDFLAGS
Warning: unsupported configuration variable CXXFLAGS
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++-4.7 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++-4.7 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... no
checking for error_at_line... yes
checking for gcc... gcc-4.7
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc-4.7 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc-4.7 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... no
checking udunits2.h usability... yes
checking udunits2.h presence... yes
checking for udunits2.h... yes
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
Checking wether in Makevars CXX_STD is set to CXX11... no
g++-4.7 -I/packages/units/units/target/gnur/include -DNDEBUG -DUDUNITS2_DIR=0    -I"/packages/units/units/target/include"    -fpic  -m32 -fplugin=/packages/units/units/target/bridge.so -DRENJIN  -fno-inline-functions  -fdisable-tree-einline -g  -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c udunits.cpp -o udunits.o
cc1plus: note: disable pass tree-einline for functions in the range of [0, 4294967295]
udunits.cpp:11:18: fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/packages/units/units/target/gnur/etc/Makeconf:202: recipe for target 'udunits.o' failed
make: *** [udunits.o] Error 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-15T15:27:52+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/445M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.renjin:renjin-maven-plugin:0.9.2726:gnur-compile (gnur-compile) on project units: Compilation of GNU R sources failed: Failed to execute Makefile -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
root@987c61d45fbf:/packages/units/units# exit
```

Anyone an idea how to tell Renjin where to find `Rcpp.h` ?

More details on the resources I consulted are in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/nuest/renjin-docker/issues/4

Comment: Sorry but I fear nobody on 'team Rcpp' (in the large) knows anything about Renjin so I suggest you seek help from them.

Comment: Right - AFAICS they like to have questions on SO, see below.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Maven to build the package, you also need to add Rcpp headers as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
  <artifactId>Rcpp</artifactId>
  <version>0.12.13-renjin-15</version>
  <classifier>headers</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can use the pom file for [plyr](https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public/org/renjin/cran/plyr/1.8.4-b98/plyr-1.8.4-b98.pom) as an example.

Note that if you just want to build a package for use with Renjin, the command line tool is far simpler:

```
renjin build units
```

This will take care of downloading the required dependencies and producing a jar file.

Do note that Renjin does not support packages which depend on external native libraries. You can see from the [automated build logs](http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/units/0.6-3/build/5) that the units package will fail because of a dependency on udunits2.

That is the reason that the units packages is [labeled as incompatible](http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/units) in our package site.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So you're saying that because of the udunits2 dependency this will not work at all? I was hoping it was more a problem of the udunits2 dependency not being available on the machine building the package.

Comment: I seem not to have the renjing command line tool:

renjin help build
/opt/renjin-0.9.2726
Unknown command build